# Volume of a solid defined by two curves rotating around $x$-axis.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I'm trying to determine the volume of the solid that is obtained by rotating around the $x$-axis the region limited by $y=2x$ and $y=x^2$. I'm trying to follow James Stewart's "Calculus. Single variable" book, but I'm not fully understanding. Is the area given by

$$
A=\int_0^2[\pi(2x-x^2)^2]dx
$$

Or should I calculate the area between these regions:

$$
A=\int(2x-x^2)dx=x^2-\frac{x^3}{3}
$$

And then the volume as:

$$
V=\int_0^2{[\pi(x^2-\frac{x^3}{3})^2]dx}
$$

I'm a bit confused here, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you speak of "area" if the question is to find a volume. That may be part of your confusion. Another hint: there are actually two different, but both perfectly correct, ways to find this volume: using the "cylindrical shells" method or using the "disks and washers" methods. This could be another source of confusion, because the integrals you would set up would be different, and yet both (if done correctly!) would yield the same answer.

Comment: Hi @zipirovich I talk about area because the book I'm following talks about area too. It says that I should calculate the area and then integrate to get the volume. But I'm not sure what area should I take. 

Quoting from the book (and translating from Spanish as best as I can): "Let S be a solid body that is between $x=a$ and $x=b$. If the area of the transverse section of S over the plane P through x and perpendicular to axis x, is A(x), where A is a continuous function, then the volume is $\int_a^b{A(x)dx}$. "

Would that definition fall with any of the two methods you described?

Comment: Just for anybody else having doubts about this, I find the video a day after Norsati gave me the answer, and helped me understand a bit more about these type of volumes. 
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-applications-of-integration-new/ab-8-11/v/disc-method-washer-method-for-rotation-around-x-axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For determining the volume of the solid that is obtained by rotating around the $x$-axis limited by $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ where $f(x)\geq g(x)$ in $[a,b]$ you have
$$V=\pi\int_a^b f^2(x)-g^2(x)\ dx$$
here
$$V=\pi\int_0^2 4x^2-x^4\ dx$$

Comment: Thank you! A quick follow-up: if it were rotated around the y-axis, would the formula change?

Comment: You are welcome. $V=\pi\int_c^d f^2(y)-g^2(y)\ dy$.